# "Index was outside the bounds of the array" VB error

Tags: vb.net

Essentially, I've run into this error quite a few times and tried to fix it, but to no avail. I've taken a look around, and it seems none of the solutions have helped me. What I'm trying to do is to populate labels with the data within my Access database. However, it will only populate 7 of the required fields, and gives me the error message "Index was outside the bounds of the array". Would anyone be able to take a quick look at my VB code and give me a hand?

```
Private Sub NR1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NR1.Click
    Try

        Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString() & "\Flix.Accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
        If cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cn.Close()
        End If
        cn.Open()

        Dim dr1 As OleDbDataReader
        Dim com1 As New OleDbCommand
        com1.CommandText = "select [Title],[Poster],[Description],[Classification], [Rating], [Stars], [Director], [MakeYear], [Price], [RunningTime] from tbl_newreleases where ID = '" & "1" & "'"
        com1.Connection = cn
        dr1 = com1.ExecuteReader

        If dr1.Read Then
            NRTitle.Text = (dr1(9)).ToString()
            NRPoster.ImageLocation = (dr1(1)).ToString()
            NRDescription.Text = (dr1(2)).ToString()
            NRClassification.ImageLocation = (dr1(3)).ToString()
            NRStars.ImageLocation = (dr1(4)).ToString()
            lblCast.Text = (dr1(5)).ToString
            lblDirector.Text = (dr1(6)).ToString
            lblYear.Text = (dr1(8)).ToString
            lblPrice.Text = (dr1(10)).ToString
            lblRunTime.Text = (dr1(7)).ToString

        End If
        cn.Close()
        dr1.Close()

        Return
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message(), MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error...")
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OleDbDataReader`'s index starts from `0` hence `dr1(10)` does not exist as per your query

```
As per your query
dr(0) will be the value of [Title] 
dr(1) will be the value of[Poster]
.........
dr(9) will be the value of [RunningTime]
```

their is no `dr(10)` exist. that's why you got `Index Out of Range exception`

please make the change as follows

```
If dr1.Read Then
    NRTitle.Text = dr1(8).ToString()
    NRPoster.ImageLocation = dr1(0).ToString()
    NRDescription.Text = dr1(1).ToString()
    NRClassification.ImageLocation = dr1(2).ToString()
    NRStars.ImageLocation = dr1(3).ToString()
    lblCast.Text = dr1(4).ToString()
    lblDirector.Text = dr1(5).ToString()
    lblYear.Text = dr1(7).ToString()
    lblPrice.Text = dr1(9).ToString()
    lblRunTime.Text = dr1(6).ToString()
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response. If I remove dr(10) and its corresponding value in CommandText, I get the same exception, and no population at all. I'm quite new to this, so I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select [Title],[Poster],[Description],[Classification], [Rating], 
[Stars], [Director], [MakeYear], [Price], [RunningTime]  
from tbl_newreleases where ID =
```

**Title = 0 Poster = 1 Description = 2 Classification = 3 Rating = 4 Stars = 5
Director = 6 MakeYear = 7 Price = 8 Runningtime = 9**

Yet the query makes little sense based on the column order. For example, You appear to be putting the value of RunningTime into NRTitle.Text, the value of Price into lblYear.txt. Still doesn't explain why the answer Sample gave did not actually work and prevent the Out of Bounds error.

```
If dr1.Read Then
    NRTitle.Text = (dr1(9)).ToString()
    NRPoster.ImageLocation = (dr1(1)).ToString()
    NRDescription.Text = (dr1(2)).ToString()
    NRClassification.ImageLocation = (dr1(3)).ToString()
    NRStars.ImageLocation = (dr1(4)).ToString()
    lblCast.Text = (dr1(5)).ToString
    lblDirector.Text = (dr1(6)).ToString
    lblYear.Text = (dr1(8)).ToString
    lblPrice.Text = (dr1(10)).ToString
    lblRunTime.Text = (dr1(7)).ToString
End If
```

Try

```
If dr1.Read Then
    NRTitle.Text = (dr1(0)).ToString()
    NRPoster.ImageLocation = (dr1(1)).ToString()
    NRDescription.Text = (dr1(2)).ToString()
    NRClassification.ImageLocation = (dr1(3)).ToString()
    NRStars.ImageLocation = (dr1(4)).ToString()
    lblCast.Text = (dr1(5)).ToString
    lblDirector.Text = (dr1(6)).ToString
    lblYear.Text = (dr1(7)).ToString
    lblPrice.Text = (dr1(8)).ToString
    lblRunTime.Text = (dr1(9)).ToString
End If
```

Then if it still fails try

```
If dr1.Read Then
    NRTitle.Text = (dr1("Title")).ToString()
    NRPoster.ImageLocation = (dr1("Poster")).ToString()
    NRDescription.Text = (dr1("Description")).ToString()
```

.... (etc etc use the names instead of ordinals

```
End If
```

and if you STILL get the Out of Bounds error, debug-step through the IF statement and see which line is causing it to jump to the CATCH block. If it's STILL unclear after that, all I can suggest are the following:

*1) Run the query in the database engine you're using, check it works and check if any values appear to be NULL*

*2) For each line in the IF statement, code each one slightly differently* (example for the first shown)

```
dim NRTitleValue as string = trycast(dr1(0),string)      
if NRTitleValue is nothing then
  NRTitle.text = ""
else
  NRTitle.Text = NRTitleValue 
end if
```

If it still fails after all that, then you have a bug that like of which I've never seen in many years as a code monkey ! Good luck, hope you get it solved.